# Cost of Builder#result for immutable collections?

Tags: scala, performance, scala-collections

How to reason about the cost of handling collections in generic way via `BuildFrom`. AFAIK, there are approximately three steps, creating the buffer, loading it, and then calling `result` on `Builder`. For example, consider the following snippet

```
def f[CC[x] <: Seq[x], A](in: CC[A])(implicit bf: BuildFrom[CC[A], A, CC[A]]): CC[A] = {
  val b = bf.newBuilder(in)         // Create the buffer          O(?)
  in.iterator.foreach(v => b += v)  // Load the buffer            O(N)
  b.result()                        // What is the cost of this?  O(?)
}
```

Now say I pass it immutable list `f(List(1,2,3))`, what is the cost of each step, and in particular, what is the cost of calling `result`? Does it make a copy of the buffer? For example, [`Vector#result`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/3da5a0d3569da9693f348ccdfd5205c3c48c2ca3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.scala#L1622) seems to be copying.

Comment: The source code you linked seems to be making copies using `java.util.Arrays.copyOf` and `copyOfRange`

Comment: @user Can any general statement be made about the performance or is it relative per collection type?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. It's probably different for each collection, but that's just wild speculation

Comment: AFAIK, using the builder is always the fastest way to build a collection.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've read this already, but this might help a bit: https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html#construction-performance

Answer (score 1):

REPL reveals concrete builder corresponding to `List` is actually `ListBuffer`

```
scala> import scala.collection.BuildFrom
     | val in = List(1,2,3)
     | val bf = implicitly[BuildFrom[List[Int], Int, List[Int]]]
     | val b = bf.newBuilder(List(1,2,3))
     | in.iterator.foreach(v => b += v)
     | b.result()
import scala.collection.BuildFrom
val in: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
val bf: scala.collection.BuildFrom[List[Int],Int,List[Int]] = scala.collection.BuildFromLowPriority2$$anon$11@448ade1
val b: scala.collection.mutable.Builder[Int,List[Int]] = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3)
val res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

where we note

```
val b: mutable.Builder[Int,List[Int]] = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3)
```

whose [`result`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/3da5a0d3569da9693f348ccdfd5205c3c48c2ca3/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala#L73) implementation states

```
// Avoids copying where possible.
override def toList: List[A] = {
  aliased = nonEmpty
  // We've accumulated a number of mutations to `List.tail` by this stage.
  // Make sure they are visible to threads that the client of this ListBuffer might be about
  // to share this List with.
  releaseFence()
  first
}

def result(): immutable.List[A] = toList
```

so it seems at least in the case of `List` copying is avoided sometimes.